# print the given number of copies of a word file via command line

Tags: cmd, ms-word, doc

*I have a SpringBoot app, which prints the given doc or docx file with word, but I can not set the number of copies.*

String cmd = "cmd.exe /c start WINWORD.EXE "" + tempFolderPath + file.getName() + "" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileCloseOrExit  /q /n";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

*It works like this, but for example I would like to print 2 copies of this, I kindof can open word two times, but I would prefer to do with a cmd parameter, if it even possible.*

CMD command looks like this:

```
start WINWORD.EXE "D://teszt1234.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileCloseOrExit /q /n
```

### [EDIT in response to macropod's comment]

Oh Thanks, although it looks bad, it is working! :-)

to print it 7 times it looks like this:

```
start WINWORD.EXE "D://teszt1234.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFileCloseOrExit /q /n
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a second instance of /mFilePrintDefault?

Answer (score 0):

Oh Thanks, althought it looks bad, it is working! :-)
to print it 7 times it looks like this:

start WINWORD.EXE "D://teszt1234.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFilePrintDefault /mFileCloseOrExit /q /n